# Hibernate JPA multiple web services updating same table

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, hibernate-mapping, spring-transactions

Below is a snippet of our source code...

```
@transactional
public void doSomething(){
  User user = (set up user fields)
  userDao.merge(user); //update USER table
  //call another web service which also updates USER table
  //do other processes
}
```

Problem is, the update from the other web service is overridden by the update from userDao.merge since it doesn't commit the merge transaction until the transactional method is done.

How do you deal with this kind of situation? I want both update from userdao.merge and the update done by the other web service to be done on the record.

Comment: I assume you're not using JTA across the applications to synchronize the transaction?  In other words, they're two separate applications which just happen to be manipulating the same database row concurrently with their own transactions.

Comment: I guess a better question would be, do you care whether the other web service fails even though the originating web service succeeds?

Comment: I'm not using it. Is that what I need to do? How do i implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Put the first update of the user in a new transactional method marked with REQUIRES_NEW propagation:

```
@Transactional
public void doSomething(){

  updateUser();

  //call another web service which also updates USER table
  //do other processes
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void udateUser(){

 User user = (set up user fields)
  userDao.merge(user); //update USER table

}
```

Before the call to webservice the inner transaction will be commited and results visible to the webservice. Just keep in mind if the webservice fails.. the first update of the user will not be rolled back.

Comment: So you're saying, rollback can only be done manually in this situation? @Transactional cannot handle it automatically?

Comment: This solution won't work either.  The problem the user has is that the call to the other web service needs to happen *after* the original `doSomething()` method has sent the merge to the database.

Comment: @Naros: so is there really a solution? or this logic we have when two web services updates the same table is not a good practice?

Comment: There are several solutions, but I need to know whether are the two web services are in separate spring applications or are they in the same spring application?

Comment: They are separate. They are two different web services deployed in the same application server

Comment: What application server are you deploying them to?

Comment: Websphere Application Server

Answer (score 0):

The biggest question here is whether you require both updates to happen atomically.  In a lot of applications, that's a necessity.  In others, it's acceptable to use eventual consistency, and that depends upon your requirements.

Should you require atomic transactions, meaning that both updates happen or they both don't, you'll need to leverage JTA-based distributed transactions across your two applications.  Application servers provide this out-of-the-box, you just need to configure your applications to use it.

A non-atomic solution would invoke using spring's `TransactionSynchronization` interface to offer an `#afterCommit()` callback:

```
@Transactional
public void doSomething() {
  // do stuff
  userDao.merge( user );

  TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(
    new TransactionSynchronization() {
      void afterCommit() {
        // call to second service somehow
      }
    }
  );
}
```

How you call that second service is entirely up to you.  You could send a JMS message with the trigger to a queue that the second web service listens to or you could call that second web service directly.

The critical part here is that the call either to the broker or the second web service needs to be fault tolerant so insure that eventual consistency contract.

Comment: if an exception happens in call to second web service, how do you roll back ?

Comment: You'd need to setup JTA and have both applications subscribe to the same distributed transaction to do that.  The spring documentation covers how to setup JTA distributed transactions.